# HTML select form into PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form with multiple select forms that can be added by the user via JS. This works fine for normal text forms, but I can't get it to work with select forms.
Here is my code:

```
<body bgcolor="#BBBBBB" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000"     scroll="no">
<form method="POST" action="datumstoevoegen2.php">
<input type="button" value="Meer datums" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" >
<input type="button" value="Datums verwijderen" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')">

<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="0">
<tr>
    <td>
        Dag:<select name="dag[]">
        <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++)
        {
            echo '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        Maand:<select name="maand[]">
        <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++)
        {
            echo '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        Jaar:<select name="jaar[]">
        <?php
        for($i = date("Y"); $i < date("Y") + 5; $i++)
        {
            echo '<option>'.$i.'</option>';
        }
        ?></select>*
    </td>
    <td>
        Tijd:<select name="tijdu[]">
        <option>00</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        </select>:<select name="tijdm[]">
        <option>00</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option></select>*
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Toevoegen">
```

And the processing code:

```
var_dump($_POST);
for($i = 0; $i < 2;$i++)
{

    $tijd[$i] = $tijdu[$i].':'.$tijdm[$i];
    $datum[$i] = $jaar[$i].'-'.$maand[$i].'-'.$dag[$i];
    echo $datum[$i];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $tijd[$i];
}
?>
```

This works fine for just one input, but if I choose multiple inputs, the second page only receives one.

The JS is here:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 50){                          // limit the     user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximaal 50 gebruikers per afspraak toegestaan.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {                             // limit the user from removing all the fields
                alert("Cannot Remove all the Passenger.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add "multiple" option after select tag, i.e:

```
<select name="dag[]" multiple="multiple">
```

..........

Comment: That worked, but now it's not a dropdown anymore, just a select box.